# Angular Universal with Azure App Service not working

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I created an Angular universal app which is working fine in local but when I try to deploy it in Azure App Service its deploying successfully but not running the app. Getting 403 forbidden.

`# Node.js with Angular

trigger:

- development

pool:
vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

stages:

- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:

  - job: Build
    pool:
    vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:

    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
      versionSpec: "18.x"
      displayName: "Install Node.js 18.x"
    - script: |
      cd app/
      npm install -g @angular/cli
      npm install  --legacy-peer-deps
      npm run build:dev:ssr

      displayName: "npm install and build"
      workingDirectory: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
      SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/app/browser"
      TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/app"
      displayName: "Copy dist browser folder to artifact staging directory"
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
      SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/app/server"
      Contents: main.js
      TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/app"
      displayName: "Copy main.js to artifact staging directory"
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      inputs:
      testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
      testResultsFiles: "**/TESTS-*.xml"
      displayName: "publish unit test results"
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive files"
      inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: zip
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop.zip
      replaceExistingArchive: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
      PathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop.zip"
      ArtifactName: "drop"
      publishLocation: "Container"
- stage: Development
  displayName: "Deploy to Development"
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:

  - deployment: DeploymentDevelopment
    pool:
    vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
    environment: Development
    strategy:
    runOnce:
    deploy:
    steps:
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: "Deploy App Service"
    inputs:
    azureSubscription: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    appName: "app"
    package: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/drop.zip"
    runtimeStack: "NODE|16-lts"
    `

this is my pipline and even tried manual deployment using FTP server in azure app service nothing seems to be working.** I think the issue is with the dist directory structure. It would be helpful if someone can help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my Azure App service folder structure like this

- wwwroot

  - browser folder

    - browser contents
  - server contents
  - webconfig

this is my webconfig

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="bin"/>
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```